# Should I use ² or <sup>2</sup>

Tags: html

In consideration of machine based readability (but not exclusively, please advice where relevant), is it better to use

```html
square²
```

or

```html
square<sup>2</sup>
```

in my HTML file (using utf-8 encoding)?

Comment: I guess `sup`, because there's only ¹²³, not any other numbers.

Comment: `<sup>` You want to try to use not use static formatting as much as possible. So we can be sure it encodes correctly (just in case). It's also more dynamic.

Comment: @Kroltan you sure? ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰

Comment: @AndrewArnold They look weird (look at the different sizes), and are encoding-specific.

Comment: I don't know why this has a "primarily option based" close request. I'm not asking for opinions, but for technical arguments to chose one or another!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use `<sup>` tag in html context.

Full official answer can be found here: [Superscripts and Subscripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Superscripts)

First reason:

> When used in mathematical context (MathML) it is recommended to consistently **use style markup for superscripts and subscripts**. This is because mathematical layout allows not just individual symbols, **but entire expressions to be superscripted or subscripted** in a regular, nested manner.

Second reason:

> However, when super and sub-scripts are to reflect semantic distinctions, it is easier to work with these meanings encoded in text rather than markup, for example, in phonetic or phonemic transcription. Otherwise, they would require markup in the middle of words, and  they may also be inadvertently changed to normal style text, when exporting to plain text. This applies to the majority of super and subscripted characters in Unicode.  **On the other hand, some user agent may support certain superscripted or subscripted characters only when used as marked up text for example, because of lack of font support for them.**

Comment: Also note that: "Mathematical expressions often use subscripts and superscripts. **Authors are encouraged to use [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/) for marking up mathematics**, but authors may opt to use sub and sup if detailed mathematical markup is not desired." -- [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements)

Comment: Actually the doc seems to say you should use unicode when available. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nux you're missing phrase `use style markup for superscripts and subscripts`

Comment: @IłyaBursov I think you might be missing `When used for these purposes, these characters should be retained and markup should *not* be used. `

Comment: I mean when you need to copy or transform the text common things like m² will work better and W3C seems to say that. When using MathML you use different markup anyway. Most of the time m² will work better, especially in context of practical a11y.

Comment: @Nux this mentioned in 2nd reason with argument as well

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the UTF-8 symbol, because the `<sup>` tag actually changes the line height slightly, a very annoying undesirable side effect.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still valid... For accessibility reasons m² is superior to `m<sup>2</sup>`.

- NVDA by default will not work with `sup`. There is an option to announce `sup`, but "m²" will be read by default as "m squared".
- JAWS seems to have (or had) problems (haven't tried, but I read it doesn't work with `sup`).
- TalkBack just breaks on `sup` and works fine with m². Though that might depend on TalkBack language.
- Firefox reading mode ignores `sup` and reads "m2" and FF works fine with m².

When you copy and paste things m² is also your best bet. It is also more readable when you edit HTML. So your best bet is to use Unicode for things like m², cm³ etc and `sup` for other things.

See also: [Brief Note on Super- and Subscript Text, 2022](https://adrianroselli.com/2022/09/brief-note-on-super-and-subscript-text.html).